# Generating $S_{p}$ (where $p$ is prime) with a shift and an involution

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $p$ be a prime, and consider $S_{p}$, the symmetric group on $p$ elements, thought of here as the group of bijections of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It is well known that, given a cyclic permutation $\sigma$ whose orbit contains all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the primality of $p$ guarantees that, for any transposition $\tau$, the elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ then generate the entirety of $S_{p}$.

Now, let $\iota$ be an involution of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., a non-identity element of $S_{p}$ of order 2). Do $\sigma$ and $\iota$ then necessarily generate $S_{p}$? If not, are there any conditions on $\iota$ more general than "$\iota$ is a transposition" which will guarantee that $\sigma$ and $\iota$ generate $S_{p}$?

Comment: If $t$ consists of an even number of transpositions, then the group generated will be a subgroup of $A_p$, so not equal to $S_p$. But there are other possibilities. They could for example generate a dihedral group of order $2p$.

Comment: If the number of transpositions of $\iota$ is small compared with $p$ (for example less that $p/4$), then $\langle \sigma,\iota \rangle$ must be $A_p$ or $S_p$. If you want to find the best possible result in this direction (which probably uses  the classification of finite simple groups), then search for papers on the minimal degree of a primitive permutation group - there has been a lot of research on this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there any papers in particular that you recommend? I'm not a group theorist (or even an algebraist), so any pointers you can offer would be much appreciated.